# How to get Number of Employees Joined or Resigned by Quarterly in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to get Number of Employees Joined or Resigned by Quarterly in SQL

I have a Table called `Mst_Employee`
fields are

```
Emp_No, Emp_JoiningDate, Emp_ResignedDate, Emp_Status
```

**Edit:** Every half a year, not quarterly.

Comment: By quarterly mean? In some order or with in some quarter of a year?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do analysis like this would be to use the DATEPART function in T-SQL. Assuming all you want is to know a specific quantity for all quarters in all years on your table, an example code would be:

```
SELECT 
      DATEPART(YEAR,Emp_JoiningDate) as [Year],
      DATEPART(QUARTER,Emp_JoiningDate) as [Quarter], 
      COUNT(1) as [Emp Count]
FROM Mst_Employee
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,Emp_JoiningDate),DATEPART(QUARTER,Emp_JoiningDate)
ORDER BY 1,2
```

This will show all the numbers of employee's joined in the quarter. The query can easily be modified to also show resigned employee's in that quarter, or you could use a separate query to show this data.

*Just an additional comment, as you're in the Employee Table, you don't need to directly state "Emp_" under all of your attributes.*

Comment: sorry not quarterly, six monthly

Comment: So you want to know the number of people resigned or joined within the space of 6 months?

Comment: Many Thanks. Yes. Like in 2013-Jan-to-Jun and 2013-July-to-Dec and so on others years. How to do this.